# Deconvolution methods in biostatistics

Tags: biostatistics, genetics

I am currently in a Biostatistics project using deconvolution methods (i.e. Cybersort, link provided below). However I have very limited background on biology (merely 1/3 of an intro to biology course) and is deeply confused on the background (i.e. why it is even linear...)

https://cibersort.stanford.edu/

Can anyone give me some introductory materials to read (I doubt if there's a textbook since it is pretty new)

Many thanks!

Comment: Why not just read the original paper?: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25822800

Comment: I read it and understood the algorithm (I even read the code). However it is hard to understand the biology behind it. It really looks like 'doing SVR among variable A and variable B...'

Comment: @failedstatistician It sounds like you're requesting a microbiology reference rather than a biostatistical one.

Comment: @failedstatistician Statistical Methods in Bioinformatics will have some useful descriptions of algorithms used in the \*omics literature. However, you will need to come up to speed with the technology used here if you are to understand the *bio*statistics.

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25822800; To assess the feasibility of leukocyte deconvolution from bulk tumors, we designed and validated a leukocyte gene signature matrix, termed LM22. It contains 547 genes that distinguish 22 human hematopoietic cell phenotypes, including seven T cell types, naïve and memory B cells, plasma cells, NK cells, and myeloid subsets.... Then

When applied with statistical filtration, CIBERSORT coupled with LM22 allows for highly sensitive and specific discrimination of human leukocyte subsets. We note that our filtration approach is likely applicable to other signature matrices and other GEP deconvolution methods.

Which means, that the inflammatory cells, human white cells in blood, that had genetic material that matched their test matrix called LM22, and was useful in identifying tumors. Why linear? They assumed that better matches are more likely for identifying tumor. If that is not what you are asking, you should narrow your question.